# Unable to Unsubscribe from the subscription of ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have subscribed to a ReplaySubject and trying to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy method. When I move away from the subscription component and come back to same component wihtout emitting the data, again its getting subscribed. May I know how can I solve this issue?

Shared.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TestCase } from './test-case-form/test-case.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
testCasesChanged = new Subject<TestCase[]>();
private startedEditing = new ReplaySubject<number>();
public startedEditing$ = this.startedEditing.asObservable();

setData(index) {
console.log("setData called", index);
this.startedEditing.next(index);
}
}
```

a.component.ts

```
export class TestFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@ViewChild('f') testForm : NgForm;
subscription: Subscription;
editIndex: number;
editMode = false;
editedTestCase: TestCase;

private testCases: TestCase[]= [];

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.sharedService.startedEditing$
.subscribe((index: number) => {
console.log("Subscribed");
this.editIndex = index;
this.editMode = true;
this.editedTestCase = 
this.sharedService.getTestCase(this.editIndex);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you're not getting the values of `startedEditing` during the second time?

Comment: it is getting the old values?

Comment: Yes it's getting old value

Comment: Second time I am loading the component without emitting the value, but it's getting subscribed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` works.

You're getting the old values in your component, because you're using a `ReplaySubject`. A `ReplaySubject` caches all values, which are emitted with it. So every time you subscribe to that subject your subscribe method is called for every value you have emitted over this `ReplaySubject`.

It is possible to change the buffer size with:

```
// Only the last emitted value is cached and emitted to every new subscriptions
private startedEditing = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
```

If you only want to get the last emitted value you can also use a `BehaviourSubject`.

But I guess you just want to use a simple `Subject`.

Comment: I tried "private startedEditing = new ReplaySubject<number>(1); ", but again its getting subscribed automatically without emitting for second time. And using Subject, its not subscribing. Not sure what is the issue

Comment: You mean that your subscription method is executed again, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I explained in my answer, it's because of the `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: By changing the ReplaySubject's buffer size does not solve the title in question. So, in short, you cannot complete a `ReplaySubject`?

Answer (score 0):

```
private startedEditing = new ReplaySubject<number>();

public startedEditing$ = this.startedEditing.asObservable(); 
// `startedEditing$` is no longer `startedEditing` they are now two different things
```

then you do

```
this.startedEditing.next(index);
```

Which updates only `startedEditing`

`startedEditing$` is never updated in the code you provide. Can you simplify and only use one?

Comment: I tried your way, but again when I navigate to this component, its getting subscribed automatically